# How to keep stats of changed URLs structure in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm working on a website re-design, migrating from a static one to Wordpress. The stats are handled by Google Analytics.

How can I say to Google Analytics that the URL:

```
http://domain.tld/blog/2014/01/24/foo-bar/
```

Is now:

```
http://domain.tld/foo-bar/
```

Because I would like to keep stats of those posts.

By the way, my pages title are the same, so I can go by this entry, but... Was wandering...

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@dedukcja's answer would work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21355749/272031) but you'll end up with a report that uses the old urls instead of the new ones. Probably not what you want.

I see 2 options here:

1. **Don't change the urls at all**, just create a Wordpress site that uses the same url structure as before. So you won't have problems with Search Engine indexes and Google Analytics reports.
2. **Change the urls** as you were planing **and just ignore** the fact that Google Analytics reports before and after won't match.

I believe 2 is the best option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think you're right and option 2 might be really the one which makes most sense, because in a few months from now, we won't care so much about _old_ stats.

Answer (score 5):

You can set trackpageview to send old url, like that:
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/blog/2014/01/24/foo-bar/']); on page: http://domain.tld/foo-bar/

There is no way to map old URLs with new ones in Google Analytics panel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 301 redirects for the legacy urls that point to the current urls. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en

You mentioned that you are using Wordpress. Here is a plugin that should make it a little easier. 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-seo-redirect-301/

Comment: This is not what I'm asking for, sorry if unclear. My concern is how to keep track of my Google Analytics traffic stats. Kind of telling to GA: "This new URL should be treated as if it was the old one, or reverse would be actually better."